# AirPlay turned off and can't be turned on

Tags: macos, airplay

I have a MacBook Air and with no apparent reason the AirPlay icon has dissapeared from the desktop. When I go to System Preferences → Displays, the status of AirPlay shows "Off" and there's no way to change it since it doesn't show the "On" option.

Answer (score 3):

The AirPlay icon in the menu bar is only shown when an AirPlay device is available, per the option ‘Show mirroring options in the menu bar *when available*’ (emphasis mine).

You're unable to change the option from Off because there are no AirPlay devices to choose from. There is no ‘On’ option ever, only a list of devices to choose, except there are no devices found so the list is empty.

[image]

There is never an AirPlay icon on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and tried a number of things suggested elsewhere; the only thing that worked for me was the Floris' [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/417916/419615), which is to sign into my iCloud account. After that, the "on" option appeared instantly and I was able to connect to my iPad via WiFi and USB.

Running BigSur 11.2.3 on MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), connecting to first-gen iPad Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure bluetooth is on, on both your laptop and your iPad. In my case, the bluetooth on my computer wasn't turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by signing in with Icloud on my Macbook Pro M1.